# Looking to program my first web accessible program

Tags: web-applications, webforms, c++-cli

I've been working on a program that basically takes stock of the food I have around my apartment and recommends meals based a different parameters.  I was hoping to program it in c++/CLI (since I have been spending a lot of time in it as late). I have also been thinking of extending it later on down the line to make managing my apartment a little easier.

While working on it, I got the great idea of somehow hosting it online so I can do things like figure out what I can have for dinner while out at work or in class.

So far, I have been looking at hosting it in an asp.net web form (I believe I can still write it in c++/CLI).  Is there an easier way to do this, such as hosting it straight from my PC?  I kinda just want to avoid paying a monthly bill just to use it on the go. I have only been programming for a few years, so this is a really new concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have IIS (which I believe comes with many newer versions of Windows) you should be able to deploy your ASP page there and host it, as you said, right from your home computer.  All you would need to access it remotely via a browser would be a known network address for your home--which would vary depending on if your IP was stable or dynamic.  Also, your computer would need to be running.

The security concerns of this approach should definitely be investigated before you go ahead with it, though, as having that app running on a public HTTP server has issues ranging from the mischievous (people spying on what you are eating) to the catastrophic (people exploiting bugs in your web app to attack your computer).